# Application preferences after remove app

Tags: ios, preferences

Is application preference stay after remove app, or after reinstall app I get cleared preferences?

I save UUID in preferences and want to know is there will be same UUID if I remove app and reinstall it after long time.

**Update:**

Is preferences backed up with iCloud and(or) iTunes and restore after reinstall app?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applications are stored in a sandbox. This means every application has its own directory, its own working space.

In that working space all data of the application gets stored. This includes documents, library files, temporary files, the application bundle, as well as the preferences file.

When a user chooses to delete an app, the whole sandbox gets removed, including those preferences.

You the answer is yes. When a user deletes and reinstals your application, his preferences will be reset.

Comment: Is preferences backed up with iCloud and(or) iTunes and restore after reinstall app?

Comment: I've never used one of both features so don't know.

Answer (score 2):

I can tell that NSUserDefaults keep info after reinstalling app.
After removing nothing will be saved, I guess.
You can make hash from device UDID and make it unique identifier for you customers.
Don't save or transport unhasned UDIDs without users permission! Keep it hashed. You can recount hash after reinstalling or removing and another installing and it will be the same every time.
Not exactly about settings, but I hope it will help you.

Comment: But UDID is deprecated since iOS 5, so how can I use it? As Apple says I'm generate UUID and save it in NSUserDefaults. Early I was use UDID and there was no problem.

Comment: I still use it and it's OK, but it is not the perfect solution.